# Query and Importrange to get the last value of the selected row of spreadsheet | Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Right now I am using this query to search for a row based on its Column 1 value. Then it takes the value from the last column. **I need a way for it to automatically find the last column in the row since some of the rows have more columns than others.**

This is what I had before, which I had manually specified the last column with a value:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("link_redacted","PriceList!A1:AZ100000"), "Select Col10 where Col1 = '5531001'",1)
```

I have tried using LOOKUP with ARRAYFORMULA I couldn't get it to work:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("link_redacted","PriceList!A1:AZ100000"), "Select (LOOKUP(1, ARRAYFORMULA(1/[Select Col1 where Col1 = '5531006']:[Select Col100 where Col1 = '5531006']<>"")[Select Col1 where Col1 = '5531006']:[Select Col100 where Col1 = '5531006']))",1)
```

Any ideas for a simpler way to do this?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Since no example is presented, I tested the formulas given but no source data is fetched.

so i created a [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

- Example is the data on the left

> **Use this formula to get the last non empty columns values.**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR( REGEXEXTRACT( TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C3:E),,ROW(C3:E)))), "[^\s]+$")))
```

[image]